# How do stored procedures work with NDB Mysql Cluster?

Tags: mysql, sharding, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

We are considering to use [Mysql Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster.html) for sharding. However I can't find how it works with stored procedures.

Is there a way to dispatch procedure invocation on particular shard, based on sharding key (passed as procedure argument or somehow separately)?

For example we have a table, sharded between 3 nodes. All rows with key `A` are stored on `node 1`. I'd like to be sure that when I run `procedure(A)`, it applies on `node1`.

*Unfortunately we can't use functions instead of procedures, because in our case they return multiple rows

Comment: Are you talking about NDB Cluster or Galera Cluster?  Please tag accordingly; "Mysql Cluster" is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You would only need to define the sharding/partitioning for the table(s) (hash based partitioning by PK is used by default) involved:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
...
)
PARTITION BY KEY(col1)
```

The data is stored in data nodes. The NDBCLUSTER storage engine in the mysqld (SQL API) nodes will use a hash generated on the partition/sharding column (PK by default) to determine which node group will/does hold that particular row. So in your case, after specifying custom partitioning for the table(s) accessed within the SP, using the column/key that the A value you're specifying references, MySQL NDB Cluster will know that all rows in the given table(s) where the partition/sharding column has a value of A will go/be on one of the three node groups.

You can see a blog post on this subject [here](http://mysqlhighavailability.com/intelligent-user-controlled-partitioning-and-writing-distribution-aware-ndb-api-applications/).